# How can I stack windows using curses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

I am using curses on Linux (arch, zsh with tmux) and trying to stack two or more windows next to one another.
Here is my basic code:

```py
def main(screen):
    # render_all_elements(screen)
    window1 = curses.newwin(100, 100, 0, 0)
    window1.border()
    window1.refresh()
    window2 = curses.newwin(10, 10, 100, 100)
    window2.border()
    window2.refresh()
    screen.getch()
    curses.nocbreak()  # Turn off cbreak mode
    curses.echo()  # Turn echo back on
    curses.curs_set(1)  # Turn cursor back on


if __name__ == "__main__":
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

It doesn't show either of the screens, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: curses does this using the panel library, which does not appear to be part of the python binding.  lacking that, careful use of touchwin and refresh works.  dialog does that.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasDickey!